# Does anyone know how to install the Python P5 Package on Windows?

Tags: python, pip

Every time I try to install the package using pip it gives me this error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\jtcap\desktop\projects\python\stuff\venv\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\jtcap\desktop\projects\python\stuff\v
env\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\jtcap\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9r4nif3r\overlay' --no-warn-script-location
 --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel 'setuptools>=30.3.0' setuptools_scm setuptools_scm_git_archive 'Cython>=0.29.2' 'numpy;
python_version=='"'"'2.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7
'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
"""
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: If I cant fix this does anyone know a good Python package to create a simple GUI, I want to make a A* Pathfinding Simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `pip install p5` if you have installed pip version 2 or `pip3 install p5` if the pip and python versions are above 3

Comment: Didn't work, it just gave me this error instead                                                               
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1